# Get linked in profile from html

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

For the past year and half i have been using this method:

```
string page = "";
WebClient WC = new WebClient();
page = WC.DownloadString("http://WWW.LINKEDINPROFILEIWANTTOOPEN.COM");
WC.Dispose();
```

and i haven't been having any problems, downloading 1000s of profiles a day and then analyzing them with a c# webservice looking through the html for the tags im after. Today i have been presented with an error code of:

> "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (999)
>   Request denied."

im guessing linked in has locked me out as they want me to use the api instead. after looking through documentation for the last hour or so it seems as if the api is set up to make your own linkedin app. i just want the standard html or just the basic fields such as name and various positions they have had over time. Also it wants me to log on as me and this just seems unnecessary.

Is the only way i can get round this problem to sign up for the api and then authorize myself and get the fields through the api or does anyone else know a solution to simply download the html for a public profile for which i have the URL

Comment: Try setting this...  WC.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)";

Comment: @leskovar no luck and i tried putting http:// www. in front of googlebot.com